# Create a Python dictionary representing composition of functions

Tags: python, parsing

I need to create a dictionary that represents the composition of functions. That is, given a composition of function, I want a dictionary where the function is the key of the dictionary and the corresponding value of the key are its arguments displayed as new dictionary.

**Here an example:**

Expression: `NUM(CEIL(NUM(MONTH(DATA))/3), 00)`

Desired output:

```
{'NUM': {'CEIL': {'/': {'NUM': {'MONTH': {'DATA': None}}, '3': None}}, '00': None}}
```

**Here my attempt:**

```
def text_formula_to_dict(text_formula):
    stack = []
    current_dict = {}
    key = ''
    special_chars = set(['(', ')', ',', '/', '*'])

    for char in text_formula:
        if char == '(':
            if key:
                stack.append((current_dict, key.strip()))
                current_dict = {}
                key = ''
        elif char == ')':
            if key:
                current_dict[key.strip()] = None
                key = ''
            if stack:
                parent_dict, parent_key = stack.pop()
                parent_dict[parent_key] = current_dict
                current_dict = parent_dict
        elif char == ',':
            if key:
                current_dict[key.strip()] = None
                key = ''
        elif char in special_chars:
            if key:
                current_dict[key.strip()] = None
                key = ''
            if char == '/' or char == '*':
                if key:
                    stack.append((current_dict, key.strip()))
                    current_dict = {}
                    key = ''
            else:
                key += char
        else:
            key += char
    if key:
        current_dict[key.strip()] = None

    return current_dict
```

However, I don't get the desired output, but this is the current one:

```
{'NUM': {'CEIL': {'NUM': {'MONTH': {'DATA': None}}, '3': None}, '00': None}}
```

So what I miss is the character "/", representing the function of division. How can I get the desired output?

Comment: You might have a look at [PyParsing](https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/). No need to reinvent this...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The problem is I never use this library before..

Comment: @Jason_mils what a great opportunity to learn something new.

Comment: When `if char == '/' or char == '*':` is executed, `key` has just been set to `''`, so `stack.append((current_dict, key.strip()))` inside `if key:` is never executed.

Comment: check out `print(ast.dump(ast.parse("NUM(CEIL(NUM(MONTH(DATA))/3), 00)"), indent=4))` and see if that helps you get to or replaces what you after.

Comment: @JonSG what is ast?

Comment: It is a standard python package. see: [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

Comment: mmm.. running the code you wrote it gives me the error "name 'ast' is not defined"